# Git I changed the HEAD by mistake, and don't know what to do

Tags: git, github, merge, version-control, branch

My project has 2 branches `main` and `feature1`. I merged them and then I tried to delete `feature1` I thought the command was `git checkout -d feature1`, but it wasn't and now it says `HEAD is now at 71bgr8p (My latest commit message)`. And it shows that I'm in a branch `((71bgr8p...))`. When I type `git branch` it says that the current branch I'm on is `HEAD detached at refs/heads/feature1`

How can I undo this?

Answer (score 2):

You are currently in the detached HEAD state.  The fix is easy, just checkout another branch, e.g. to return to the `main` branch do:

```
git checkout main
```

As for deleting the `feature1` branch, use the following:

```
git branch -d feature1        # to delete the local branch
git push -d origin feature 1  # to delete the remote branch
```